# How to access custom global using menu token module?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, tokens

In a project I'm working on, there's a global variable called School Year. There's a page where the user selects the school year to be used throughout the session or until they change it. According to the page, it's stored as "field_school_year_term_". The School Year was created via taxonomy, and what I need is to make it so that the selected school year is made a part of a set of urls.

To do this, we're using the [Menu Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module. We've tried a large amount of available tokens for it, such as:

```
/foo/[school-year:id]/bar
/foo/[school-year:school_year]/bar
/foo/[current-user:field_school_year_term]/bar
/foo/[user:field_school_year_term]/bar
```

Each of these has failed to replace the token, even while switching around the methods to replace the tokens. I do have `Use tokens in title and in path` checked, as well as `[site:url]` before the path we want to make.

Basically, how can I access the global field using menu tokens, and what other suggestions do you have? I'd like to avoid having to code in a redirect (though that solution may prove handy to resolve this issue).